# How to implement RecyclerView with key-value pairs

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a map with key that will never change, that contain some list of different data.

I want to implement `RecyclerView` that contain a header(the key), and underneath that list of all the values for a given key.

Any idea how can I implement this?

Until now I worked only with `ArrayList` inside RecycleView, so I have hard time to understand how can I implement such a thing

Comment: If you want a recycler view with differents viewholders, you can to use an arraylist and override in the adapter getItemViewType, that returns the layout id to create the viewholder.  In the onCreateViewHolder you receive this data in viewType and then initialize the right viewholder.  This is the easy way, but there is another options more cools to respect the open/close principle.

Comment: Check this out.. https://github.com/timehop/sticky-headers-recyclerview